# Solve System of Linear Equations

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, solver

I have a column vector of linear equations. each equations is fun of series of variables (x1,x2,......x20,y1,y2,.....,y20), 
all the equaions=0

how to solve these equations

```
from Matlab help 
sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3], [x, y, z]);
xSol = sol.x
ySol = sol.y
zSol = sol.z
```

how to call the matrix instead of each equations eqn1,eqn2,...especially for the very large number of equations

the same for the variables can call them as vectors instead of individuals/one by one.

Also, I keep getting the same warning

[Warning: Cannot solve symbolically. Returning a numeric
approximation instead. ]

Thanks

Comment: What kind of equations do you have? I mean: how are they represented? A cell array of a function handle? You could derive the matrix and simply invert it. Do you have a known term or is it inside the equation; as in x-3=0, e.g.? I will derive A and b and then the solution would just be A\B (maybe with a refinement). Is it what you are after? Then question is how to derive A and B from a vector of handles? Please clarify.

Comment: My equations are in a vector size of (40*1). each element is an equation. variables are defined earlier in a vector as well, say X size (40*1); X1, X2,X3,X4...etc. The equation has its variable but they are not in sequence as they created from matrix multiplication in a for-loop. For example, the eq-1 in form of, ax3+bx2+cX1+ex4.etc.

Comment: (2): As the variables are not in sequence, do sol.x1 is the solution of the variable x1,or the solution of the first variable in the equation. what if the variable sequence is changing in each equation i.e.;(Eq1, X3-2X1+5X3=0, Eq2, X2+2x3-x1=0)

Comment: I still do not get how these equations are represented and, above all, why you chose to represent those as 2X1 blah blah

1) what kind of data are those? Do you use symbolic toolbox? And why?
2) can you please post a toy example of the code which generates the equations? What are you trying to solve? My guess is that you do not need to go through the symbolic equation solver, but simply to invert a matrix; but I may very well be wrong: I am not sure I understood your original problem. Few toy data and relevant code would clarify that.

Comment: E=sym('E',[21 1]);G=sym('G',[21 1]);                                                         
Eq1=(H_Real-FF(:,1)).^2+(H_imag-FF(:,2)).^2; %H is a matrix with complex variables. H dim is 89*21, no. of varaibles 42. E1:E21, G1:G21.

EmE=sym(ones(42,1));
for ij=1:21
    Em1=0;Em2=0;
    for jj=1:88
    Em1=Em1+diff(Eq1(jj),E(ij,1)); 
    Em2=Em2+diff(Eq1(jj),G(ij,1));
    end
    EmE(ij,1)=Em1;EmE(ij+21,1)=Em2;
end
sol =vpasolve(EmE,[E,G]);
sol.E1;sol.E2;........;Sol.E21;  % the same 2 quesions above please